# SQL Asking To Declare Variable That Is Declared

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am attempting to run this SQL Syntax, but I keep getting an error of:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@startDate".

However, it looks to me that the variable is already declared at the beginning of my procedure.  Why is the error being thrown, and what do I need to do to fix it?

I am using this syntax to call my stored procedure:

```
exec [dbo].[DoThis] '01/01/2015','01/31/2015'
```

And this is full procedure which presents compile error above.

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[DoThis]
(
  @startDate datetime,
  @endDate datetime
)
As 


Declare @storename varchar(500), @dblocation varchar(500), @sql varchar(max)

Select storename, dblocation
INTO #allstores
FROM tbl_allstores
where sales >= '1,000,000'

Declare c1 Cursor For

Select storename, dblocation
FROM #allstores

Open c1 

Fetch Next From c1 Into @storename, @dblocation

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Begin
  Set @sql = 'Insert Into #storeinfo (storename, employeename, employeeaddress, employeephone) '
            +'Select '''+@storename+''' As ''storename'', '
            +'employeename, employeeaddress, employeephone '
            +'From '+@dblocation+' '
            +'where employeestatus = ''Active'' '
            +'and CAST(hiredate As Date) BETWEEN CAST(@startDate As Date) AND CAST(@endDate As Date) '
  Print(@sql)
  exec(@sql)

  Fetch Next From c1 Into @storename, @dblocation

End

Close c1
Deallocate c1


Select * from #storeinfo

Drop Table #allstores
Drop Table #storeinfo
```

Comment: It is best to pass dates as `'YYYY-MM-DD'`.

Comment: Because it is the [ISO 8601 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for formatting dates. There is no ambiguity when parsing dates that way. Some locales have MM/DD/YYYY others have DD/MM/YYYY etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you `exec(@sql)` this creates a new context with its own local variables, and you have not passed the `@startDate` value into that context.

Instead, declare parameters for your SQL string like this:

```
exec sp_executesql @sql, '@startDate datetime, @endDate datetime', 
      @startDate, @endDate;
```

These names will now be available to your SQL, and the parameters will be passed to them.

**This method is better because it treats the variables as parameters** which is safer because it reduces the risk of SQL Injection.

As an additional tip, you should also pass @storeName as a parameter. As far as I know  you cannot pass @dbname as a parameter, so you should instead ensure that it is quoted correctly.

So the full thing would be:

```
Set @sql = 'Insert Into #storeinfo (storename, employeename, employeeaddress, employeephone) '
        +' Select @storename As ''storename'', '
        +' employeename, employeeaddress, employeephone '
        +' From '+QUOTENAME(@dblocation)+' '
        +' where employeestatus = ''Active'' '
        +' and CAST(hiredate As Date) '
        +' BETWEEN CAST(@startDate As Date) AND CAST(@endDate As Date) '


Print(@sql)
exec sp_executesql @sql, 
    '@startDate datetime, @endDate datetime, @storeName nvarchar(100)', 
    @startDate, @endDate, @storeName;
```

Comment: The sql actually takes the value from @dblocation problem free, which is why I thought I could just pass in the date values the same way.

Answer (score 3):

Changing to:

```
+'and CAST(hiredate As Date) BETWEEN CAST(''' + @startDate + ''' As Date) AND CAST(''' + @endDate + ''' As Date) '
```

I would think would work, or at least be close.  Your issue is `@startDate` and `@endDate` are not actually declared within the separate scope that is executing your dynamic sql.

Basically `exec(@sql)` is a separate scope from the stored proc scope that is actually declaring your `@startDate` and `@endDate`.

Comment: This gives me an error of: `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`